# Does jquery $document.ready wait for json files to be loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, document-ready

I get HTML configuration data from a json file. When that has loaded, I need to make sure that the document is ready before plugging the HTML into existing elements.

```
    var cfg;
    function getJSONconfigdata() {
        $.getJSON("/quizdata.json", function (json) {
            cfg = json;          
            //Now do everything else
            init();
        });
    }
    getJSONconfigdata()

    function init(){
        //Plug cfg values into existing dom elements. but they may not exist yet.
        //...
    }
```

init() is called after the json file has been parsed, but **how do I make sure the dom is also ready?** I have tried $(function (){ init(); }); but cant make it work - it seems to fire before json is loaded.

Comment: Not it does not, Your init belongs in the callback and the getJSONconfigdata belongs in the ready

Comment: There's no reason to delay the JSON call until the ready event.

Comment: "I have tried $(function (){ init(); }); but cant make it work" — It should work fine. You should provide a [mcve]. I'm guessing you put it somewhere other than where you currently have `init()`. Note that there's no point in having a function that does nothing but call another function, you could just `$(init)`.

Comment: Yes, I had wrapped init() in document.ready. Well the doc was ready but the json wasn't. When I asked for a cfg value, I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined." 
       function getJSONconfigdata() {...} |
            $(function () {
                init();
            });
|
        function init(){
            console.log(cfg.stem);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `$(document).ready()` runs when the DOM is prepared for JS. When many people use jQuery they will put all of their code that will interact with page elements within the `$(document).ready()` statement to ensure that. So

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var cfg;
    function getJSONconfigdata() {
        $.getJSON("/quizdata.json", function (json) {
            cfg = json;          
            //Now do everything else
            init();
        });
    }
    getJSONconfigdata()
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, excellent. I was looking at it back to front - get json then dom - putting document ready outside this function. +1 but I'm too new to vote!

Comment: I would do `$(function() { $.getJSON("/quizdata.json", init) })`  - and have `function init(json) { .... }`

Comment: @mplungian yes that's more elegant. So many right ways to do things.